# Is cudaFree(0) guaranteed to do anything?

Tags: cuda, idioms, null-pointer

Mark Harris [wrote here once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12311042/1593077) - albeit 9 years ago by now - that:

> In fact `cudaFree(0)` is commonly used to initialize the CUDA context!

and I see this (somewhat questionable) idiom used in this [example program repository](https://github.com/NVIDIA/multi-gpu-programming-models) of NVIDIA's, used in presented in this year's GTC.

So, is `cudaFree(0)` guaranteed to actually do anything?

Comment: Empirically, it does nothing except in the situation where there is no current runtime context, in which case it will (possibly in conjunction with cudaSetDevice) trigger lazy context establishment or binding to an existing driver API context. But none of this is documented and there are no guarantees (and the exact heuristics of this have subtly changed several times since I started working with the runtime API in 2008)

Comment: from [the docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ga042655cbbf3408f01061652a075e094): "If devPtr is 0, no operation is performed."

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Well, yes, but that refers to the pointer. As talonmies and Mark Harris pointed out, operations are performed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formally - no, it isn't guaranteed to do anything.

Following the sages' comments:

The documentation, if anything, suggests no action. Empirically, using `cudaFree(0)`, possibly after a `cudaSetDevice()`, forces the establishment of a context. I would speculate it does something similar to `cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain()` (which is what one might use in a naive implementation of `cudaFree()` using the driver API).

Comment: What is the use of explicitely creating a context that way?

Comment: @Silicomancer: Any context, or the primary context?